# How to have a matrix aligned with the rest of an equation?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

When I include a matrix in an equation, the first part of the equation is separated off to the left of the page, while the matrix is spaced away in its own centred area on its own line.  Here is what I am currently doing:

```
\[
$M^{-T} = \frac{1}{|det(M)|}$  \begin{bmatrix}
a_{22} & - a_{21} \\
-a_{12} & a_{11} 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

What is the correct approach for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove those `$` symbols: you're getting an error message for that.

Comment: Should it be `M^{-T}` or `M^{-1}` on the LHS of the equation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The notation `\[` and `\]` puts TeX in (display) math mode, meaning you don't have to enter math mode again using `$` ... `$`. In fact, this causes an error. Barring that, the alignment should be fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  M^{-T} = \frac{1}{|\det(M)|}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \phantom{-}a_{22} & -a_{21} \\
      -a_{12} & \phantom{-}a_{11} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}​
```

In the above example I've played around with some parameters:

- Right-aligned all the entries in the `bmatrix` (using `\phantom`) so positive and negative scalar quantities line up. This may be personal preference.
- [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text` which sets its argument in the correct font size (although it doesn't matter in your specific case) in text mode. You'll notice a difference in the spacing between `det` and `\text{det}` in math mode. Moreover, in math mode, `det` is intepreted as `d` multiplied by `e`, multiplied by `t`, which is not correct. LaTeX also provides `\det` natively for this, defined as a math operator (and therefore has a marginally different spacing, but better in general).

Comment: The `\text` lesson is a good one, but `amsmath` also provides `\det` directly.

Comment: @Werner In any case `\operatorname` should be used, not `\text`, if the operator is not predefined. Of course you can predefine it with `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: @egreg: Speaking of which: am I the only one who sets a shorthand `\on = \operatorname` and just doesn't bother with `\DeclareMathOperator` at all?

Comment: @RyanReich When an operator is used several times, I find it clearer to define a command. For a couple of applications, `\operatorname` is not a problem. That's me, of course.